# Retrieve google analytics data without authenticating?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I want to retrieve page views for my website using the google api. I need to use the core reporting API to do this:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/

I want, on page load, to pull down data about page views for my website. At the moment I'm having problems seeing how to achieve this without first needing to manually authenticate the user (via a popup asking for a users google credentials). I don't want this - I simply want to retrieve some data for a given Google analytics profile.

I've generated a client id and an api id and am ready to go but can't find a clear example of how to query the api in the way I need.

Any ideas where in the documentation I can find what I need?

Comment: Do it server side then output it to the user

Comment: Is that the only way? Is it not possible to use the js api to do this?